# Rails is slow in Rancher based Docker environment with Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, rancher

We're using a Rancher based Docker environment.
The server is well equipped and I don't feel any performance issues.
But the start performance and the performance of the console is heavily slow.

- **2 minutes** to start the puma-Server (On my local VM: 10 seconds)
- **1 minute 56 seconds** to access the console `rails c` (On my local VM: 7 seconds)
- 17 minutes! to update 70000 from 100000 Records with that "oneliner" in the rails console. **Just 70 records per second**. The select itself takes just 31ms.

```rb
Object.where(view: 0).each { |obj| obj.update_columns(view: 1) }
```

I think this should be much faster. I tested it when I was the only user in the database.

I've also compared my local VM (2 cores 3GB RAM)

```rb
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { 1000.times do Object.first.update_columns(view: 0) end }
end
```

**Local**

```
       user     system      total        real
   2.472000   0.216000   2.688000 (  4.719130)
```

**Server**

```
       user     system      total        real
   1.961856   0.164141   2.125997 ( 14.161671)
```

So does anyone got an idea what can slow down everything so much?

According to PgHero, the database is okay, there are no useless indexes.

Please ask if you need more information.

**Hardware**
The CPU and the ram are at 30% - everything quiet.
The process of the mentioned "oneliner" used 5,7% of one core
*CPU*: Intel® Core™ i7-6700 Quad-Core
*RAM*: 64 GB DDR4 RAM
*HDD*: 1TB SSD

**Environment**
*OS*: Ubuntu 18.04.1
*Ruby*: 2.6.6
*Rails*: 5.2.4.2
*PostgreSQL*: 10.12

PostgreSQL is not stored in a pod, but directly on the machine, accessed via ip     172.17.0.1

*Rancher*: v2.2.3
*User Interface*: v2.2.41
*Helm*: v2.10.0-rancher10
*Machine*: v0.15.0-rancher6-1

**Project**
A middle sized project with about 74 gems and 167 models and 1128 routes.

```sh
time bundle exec rake environment
real    0m2,164s
user    0m1,717s
sys     0m0,423s
```

```rb
Benchmark.ms { Rails.application.eager_load! }
=> 16.18773490190506
```

The Main Dockerfile is using a standard ruby-slim-image.

**Dockerfiles**

mytag/my_ruby_2_6_6:

```sh
FROM ruby:2.6.6-slim
LABEL maintainer="my@email.com"

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

# Set the locale
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales

RUN sed -i -e 's/# de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8

ENV LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 \
    LANGUAGE=de_DE:de \
    LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8

RUN echo "set input-meta on" >> /etc/inputrc && \
    echo "set output-meta on" >> /etc/inputrc && \
    echo "set convert-meta off" >> /etc/inputrc && \
    echo "export LANG=de_DE.utf8" >> /etc/profile && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime

# install bundler
RUN gem install bundler

# install some tools
RUN apt-get install -y cron build-essential git nodejs imagemagick libpq-dev

# Rails ENV
ARG RAILS_ENV=production

# BUNDLER options
ARG BUNDLER_OPTS=" --without development test"

# clean up
RUN apt-get autoremove -y

# dummy start command
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

```sh
FROM mytag/my_ruby_2_6_6
LABEL maintainer="my@email.com"

ARG RAILS_ENV=production

COPY Gemfile* ./

# install rubygem
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN bundle config git.allow_insecure true && \
    bundle install --jobs 20 $BUNDLER_OPTS

COPY . /app

RUN rails assets:precompile

WORKDIR /app

# Expose Puma port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start up
CMD ["docker/startup.sh"]
```

The script *docker/startup.sh* is a simple task to to migrations and start the server.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
bundle exec rake db:migrate
echo "Migration Done!"

bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

**Rancher YAML** (an extraction // anonymized)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "58"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-06-03T19:03:28Z"
  generation: 75
  labels:
    workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: deployment-railsapp-railsapp
  name: railsapp
  namespace: railsapp
  resourceVersion: "2133509"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1beta2/namespaces/railsapp/deployments/railsapp
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 5
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: deployment-railsapp-railsapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cattle.io/timestamp: "2019-06-18T12:40:43Z"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        workload.user.cattle.io/workloadselector: deployment-railsapp-railsapp
    spec:
      affinity: {}
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: 172.17.0.1
        image: myapp/railsapp:master-4996
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 70
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 3000
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        name: railsapp
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 70
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 2
          tcpSocket:
            port: 3000
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities: {}
          privileged: false
          procMount: Default
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          runAsNonRoot: false
        stdin: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        tty: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 5
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-06-18T12:33:27Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-06-18T12:33:27Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2019-06-11T08:22:59Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2019-06-21T13:11:49Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "railsapp-958579c56" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 75
  readyReplicas: 5
  replicas: 5
  updatedReplicas: 5
```

What I found out, the server is starting really fast, when I remove all routes. But I have no explenation for that.

Comment: Are you running a docker build on the cluster? Where is the cluster located? How many nodes are there in the cluster? Is the Rails pod running on the same node as PostGreSQL service?

Comment: @leodotcloud
Yes a docker build is running. There is just one cluster on one node. The Rails pod is running on the same node as PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is the cluster node running in the cloud or is it a VM running on your laptop? Another question, why do you have to do a docker build everytime? Can't you build and push it to registry for use on the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: The Cluster node is a dedicated webserver. My local VM is an environment without rancher and docker. Just an ubuntu with a rails server running.
According your last question, is that relevant for the speed of the server itself?

Comment: Can you SSH to your dedicated webserver and do the same docker build to check the times natively? Your VM and the webserver are two different environments. The network connectivity is different, the settings could be different unless you are using the same VM image or some process to have identical environments. Are there other workloads running on that webserver machine which could impact the docker build?

Answer (score 2):

See that "resources: {}" in your YAML? You forgot to specify it and that's most likely the cause. I never used Rancher but in Kubernetes if you don't specify resources - it will specify it for you and most likely it will use some low value.

So you should specify resources for your application. Simple example is below:

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "8Gi"
    cpu: "2"
  limits:
    memory: "8Gi"
    cpu: "2"
```

Read more about compute resources for containers here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect on the performance. Still the same loading time as an identical Pod without resources restrictions.

Comment: That's really weird. So the difference in running application in Kubernetes and locally on the same node is that much?

Comment: Local means on my local machine on a VM with zust 3GB RAM and 2 CPUs.